# Life of a dog after losing her companion she had from birth

Tags: dogs, psychology, multi-pet-families, death

I had two German Shepherds, Daisy and her daughter Dalmi. Since her birth, Dalmi was living with her mother as her companion.

Despite me and my family also being a part of their life, I still think that it plays an important role in dogs' lives if they live with each other all the time. Daisy passed away last Tuesday. So far, I have not yet noticed any visible trauma in Dalmi.

**But could this incident and Daisy's absence harm Dalmi in any way? And how should I keep her happy and protect her from any kind of trauma?**

Comment: I'm on my phone so hard to type a real answer but I'm in a similar situation right now, albeit with cats. The consistent advice I find is that the most important things are to *keep her normal routine*, and to *not treat her differently*. With the latter, in particular, things like crying, holding her, etc. may seem natural but are actually red flags to the pet that things have changed significantly and in a potentially scary way. Also some loss of appetite, possible depression, etc. can be natural and can take anywhere from days to months to resolve. So keep her active and healthy.

Comment: [Check this out](http://healthypets.mercola.com/sites/healthypets/archive/2015/09/19/helping-surviving-pet-deal-with-loss.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Honestly they do quite well, for dogs who are dependent on a canine companion you will see anxiety/stress when they are left alone. If she hasn't shown any new off-behaviors then she is coping well and you shouldn't need to worry.

I wouldn't change anything in her routine, animals in general like routine so the more you keep it on track the better. However if Daisy was keeping Dalmi active and tuckered out you may need to increase play-time (more exercise) to prevent boredom.